# HTML 5 area tag :focus outline color not visible in Safari

Tags: html, sass, accessibility, area, outline

I use a `<area>` tag on my site. Regarding accessibility, if you TAB through area's I want to change the outline-color to black.

I am using scss (sass). I tried:

```
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

area  {
    &:focus {
      outline: #000000 3px solid !important;
    }
  }
```

But in Safari browser it doesn't show any border or color on :focus or when I TAB through the area's???

This is my `<area>`:

```
<area shape="poly" alt="My alt text" coords="162,250,183,244,201,244,211,244,203,232,198,223,178,216,169,213,156,216,153,227,135,227,124,230,120,237,120,248,123,257,140,260" href="my-link" title="My-Title" target="_blank">
```

Comment: I've had problems in the past with outlines not showing because overflow was set to hidden, try `overflow: visible` on area.

Comment: using 'border' inside of your nested area:focus works.  Can you use border instead of outline?

Comment: @Davey you mean `area {overflow: visible; }` ? I tried this but it is not working..

Comment: @JordanBarber I think it's not possible to use border instead of outline on <area> tag.. I tried it but it's not working I think... How do you use border inside on <area> tag?

Comment: @meez yes that is what I meant, I thought it was worth a shot. Is the focus selector working at all in safari? Try adding opacity: 0.5 on focus to test this.

Comment: @meez I am able to use border instead of outline in your fiddle and it works fine.

Comment: @JordanBarber do you have an example? Because I was not able to get a nice border around the various provinces on my map... Thanks